# Calling Parameterized Methods in Other Methods

Tags: c#

I don't know if I have chosen a correct headline, but I do hope I have.

I am currently trying to get a better understand of methods in C#, and in doing so I thought that I'd make a simple `BankAccount` example.

So, what I have is this:

1. I have three methods:

   - a method to "deposit" money.
   - a method to "withdraw" money.
   - a method to print everything (name, balance).

```
class BankAccount
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    private string _Name;

    public int Balance
    {
        get { return _Balance; }
        set { _Balance = value; }
    }
    private int _Balance;

    public BankAccount(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Balance = 1000;
    }

    // deposit money
    public int Deposit(int balance)  
    {
        Balance += balance;

        return Balance;
    }

    // withdraw money
    public int WithDraw(int balance) 
    {
        Balance -= balance;

        return Balance;
    }

    // print to console
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Owner: " + Name
             + "\nYour current balance is: $" + Balance);             
    }
}
```

What I want to do is this:

> if I call "deposit" in Main and pass it a value, I want the print method to show me the amount (same goes for "withdraw").

How do I achieve this? I have tried some controle statements, but I don't know how to do this correctly with methods that have parameters?

I hope that someone can shed some light on this issue of mine.

Comment: I'm confused - you want the `Withdraw` method to print something or you want to call the `Print` method after each withdraw?

Comment: in your `WithDraw` and `Deposit` methods, call `Print()` before returning the `Ballance`?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean either. Show us where are you initialize and calling this class methods

Comment: You can call the `Print()` method either through the instance or inside the `Deposit()` and `WithDraw()` methods.

Comment: I want the print method to tell show (when called in Main) how much has been withdrawn or deposited. Basically, if I call the withdraw in Main - x.withDraw(400); - I want the print method to show me that 400 has been withdrawn from the bank account -- I hope that this helped to understand. I apologize for confusing.

Comment: @Prittex Sounds like you need different `Print` methods for each activity - otherwise you're going to have to provide more data to `Print` so that it knows what you want it to print.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You could just call `Console.WriteLine` from within `Deposit` and `Withdraw` (as those are currently the only places where the deposited/withdraw amount is known). You could also keep a list of all past transactions and expose that via a property or method, so they can be printed later. It all depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. *Bytheway, you don't need to write out getters and setters in full: `public string Name { get; set; }` will do.*

Comment: @PieterWitvoet You're right. It cannot get more simple than that. I think that I was trying to make it way more complex than it had to be :O :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is overload the method to do more than one thing, for example you can create an overload that takes an `int` (the balance being subtracted or added) and a `string` saying which action happening, then you can have this method in the code **along with the already existing one**

```
public void Print(int balance, string action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Owner: " + Name
         + "\nYour current balance is: $" + Balance
         + "and you " + action + ": $" + balance);
}
```

This could be used by passing the string `action` as `"withdrew"` or `"deposited"` depending on which method calls it.

Using this overload allows you to both output the original `Print` method, if they want to know their balance but never withdrew or deposited, and the new version all depending on which parameters you pass

For more information on overloading see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx) MSDN page

Example Usage:

```
public int Deposit(int balance)  
{
    Balance += balance;
    Print(balance, "deposited"); //prints current balance AND action that was completed
    return Balance;
}

public void ShowBalance()
{
    Print(); //Just prints current balance
}
```

Comment: That won't work. You should add another parameter to show the amount of the last operation.

Comment: @Pikoh That's what balance is, I am using their variable names, the actual balance is called `Balance` with a capital B and the amount used in the action is called `balance` with a lower case

Comment: It confused me too, but I thought it would be best to use as it follows the naming convention set out by OP

Comment: Just to complete, i think you should add a example call to this method :)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre It's working! I just have one more question. What if I call the methods more than once? If I do that, the name and current balance will just get printed out again :(

If I call both WithDraw and Deposit, the name of the owner and current balance will be shown twice :(

Comment: Of course, that is what the method does, if you want to fix that, look in the method that takes parameters and take out the lines saying `"Owner: " + Name
         + "\nYour current balance is: $" + Balance` and just make it say `Console.WriteLine("You have " action + ": $" + balance);`